# How do you create an input layout for passing a uint4 to a vertex shader in D3D10?

Tags: c++, directx10

I am trying to pass in a uint4 into the shader but my input layout keeps failing when trying to load the shader.

**shader.fx**

```
uint4  values : UINT4_0;  // VertexInput
```

**Input layout**

```
{ "UINT4", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_UINT, 0, 0, D3D10_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 }
```

Does that seem right?

I am a bit confused why there is an error here.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @JoshPetrie I haven't written the handle for the Sysout for the error. My program just crashes trying to `CreateInputLayout` which almost 100% of time for me was because of an error in the input description. And this was the only thing I changed which caused to me to get the error. And I can't for the life of me figure where the input description is not correct. This issue was also caused when I tried to input a semantic that had a number attached to it...i.e. "FLOAT4_0" and "UINT4_0", however input semantics like "COLOR0" and "POSITION0" always work.

Comment: For a semantic called `UINT4_0` in the shader, you probably need to set the name to `"UINT4_"` in the input layout, not `"UINT4"`.

Comment: @NathanReed Yes, that works. I have added that to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this and I thought I will post it here since it will help others. In order to pass in a `UINT4` into an HLSL, you must have the following:

**1. InputLayout**

```
{ "UINT4_", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_UINT, 0, D3D10_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT, D3D10_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 }
```

**2. InputVertex**

```
 uint4 valuesUnsigned: UINT4_0;
```

**3. Input Data Structure**

```
struct UINT4__
    {
        unsigned int a1;
        unsigned int a2;
        unsigned int a3;
        unsigned int a4;

        UINT4__(){};

        UINT4__(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, unsigned int z, unsigned int w)
        {
            a1 = x;
            a2 = y;
            a3 = z;
            a4 = w;
        }
    };
```

*EDIT: Added what NathanReed has said in one of his comments on this question.*